# Max of hourly sum per month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a report which shows the summed quantity per hourly timeperiod.
I have a visual showing quantity per period, a time series, and markers showing top N values for the whole selected period.
Example time series visual :

[image]

I want to add markers for the maximum value per month but struggle with this.
The end user should be able to filter on DateTimeColumn, ID and Product.

My attempts have been something in these lines:

```
DEFINE 
Var _S = ADDCOLUMNS( 
        'Table'  
        ,"DateTimeColumnMonth",FORMAT('Table'[DateTimeColumn],"yyyymm")
        ,"@QSumMeasure",Sum('Table'[Quantity])
        )   
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS(
    _S  
    ,"MonthRank"
    ,RANKX(_S[DateTimeColumnMonth]
        ,[@QSumMeasure]
        )
    )
```

This gives me an error message saying that it isn't a valid table.
If I try with summarizecolumns I get the same answer.
My trouble is that I don't understand how to do aggregation on an aggregation with filtering from slicers.

1.) I assume that I'm thinking about this the wrong way. What am I missing here? I assume that I cannot add a calculated column since the value needs to change based on the filters.

2. ) There is probably a simple solution when it is aggregated on month, week, et.c. but I would like to know how to do it more generally, for example on Product instead of month.

If you have examples or posts that explains these things I would be grateful. I want to understand how to think when solving these kinds of examples.

In T-SQL I would have done something like this:

```sql
with t as (
            Select      DateTimeColumn
                    ,datetrunc(month,DateTimeColumn) as DateTimeColumnMonth
                    ,Sum(Quantity) as QSumMeasure 
            from [Table] 
            where   ID in (@IDFilter) 
                    and Product in (@ProductFilter)
                    and DateTimeColumn in (@DateTimeColumnFilter)
            group by DateTimeColumn
                    ,datetrunc(month,DateTimeColumn)
)
,tt as (
        Select      DateTimeColumn
                ,QSumMeasure
                ,Dense_Rank() over (Partition by DateTimeColumnMonth order by QSumMeasure Desc) as RN
        from t
)
Select      DateTimeColumn
        ,case when RN=1 then QSumMeasure else 0 end as IsHighestMonthValue
From tt
```

I want the result to be this for the example table.

| DateTimeColumn | IsHighestMonthValue |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-29 19:00:00 | 24 |
| 2024-02-02 17:00:00 | 30 |
| ... | 0 |

Dax code for example table:

```
Table = 
DATATABLE(
    "ID", STRING,
    "Product", STRING,
    "DateTimeColumn", DATETIME,
    "Quantity", DOUBLE,
    {
        {"1", "A","2024-01-29 17:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-29 17:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-29 17:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-29 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-29 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-29 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-29 19:00:00", 8 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-29 19:00:00", 8 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-29 19:00:00", 8 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-29 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-29 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-29 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-29 21:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-29 21:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-29 21:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-29 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-29 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-29 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-29 23:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-29 23:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-29 23:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 00:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 00:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 00:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 01:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 01:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 01:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 03:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 03:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 03:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 05:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 05:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 05:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 07:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 07:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 07:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 09:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 09:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 09:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 11:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 11:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 11:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 13:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 13:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 13:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 15:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 15:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 15:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 17:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 17:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 17:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 21:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 21:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 21:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-30 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-30 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-30 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-30 23:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-30 23:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-30 23:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 00:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 00:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 00:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 01:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 01:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 01:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 02:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 02:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 02:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 03:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 03:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 03:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 04:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 04:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 04:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 05:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 05:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 05:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 06:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 06:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 06:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 07:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 07:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 07:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 08:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 08:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 08:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 09:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 09:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 09:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 10:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 10:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 10:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 11:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 11:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 11:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 12:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 12:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 12:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 13:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 13:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 13:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 14:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 14:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 14:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 15:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 15:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 15:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 16:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 16:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 16:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 17:00:00", 7 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 17:00:00", 7 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 17:00:00", 7 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 18:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 18:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 18:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 19:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 19:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 19:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 20:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 20:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 20:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 21:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 21:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 21:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "B","2024-01-31 22:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-01-31 22:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-01-31 22:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-01-31 23:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "B","2024-01-31 23:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "A","2024-01-31 23:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 00:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 00:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 00:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 01:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 01:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 01:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 03:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 03:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 03:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 05:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 05:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 05:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 07:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 07:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 07:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 09:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 09:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 09:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 11:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 11:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 11:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 13:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 13:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 13:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 15:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 15:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 15:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 17:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 17:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 17:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 21:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 21:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 21:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-01 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-01 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-01 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-01 23:00:00", 1 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-01 23:00:00", 1 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-01 23:00:00", 1 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 00:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 00:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 00:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 01:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 01:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 01:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 02:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 03:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 03:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 03:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 04:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 05:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 05:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 05:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 06:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 07:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 07:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 07:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 08:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 09:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 09:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 09:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 10:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 11:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 11:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 11:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 12:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 13:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 13:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 13:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 14:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 15:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 15:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 15:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 16:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 17:00:00", 10 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 17:00:00", 10 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 17:00:00", 10 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 18:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 19:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 20:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 21:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 21:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 21:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-02 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-02 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-02 22:00:00", 2 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-02 23:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-02 23:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-02 23:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 00:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 00:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 00:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 01:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 01:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 01:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 02:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 02:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 02:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 03:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 03:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 03:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 04:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 04:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 04:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 05:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 05:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 05:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 06:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 06:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 06:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 07:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 07:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 07:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 08:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 08:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 08:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 09:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 09:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 09:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 10:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 10:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 10:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 11:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 11:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 11:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 12:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 12:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 12:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 13:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 13:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 13:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 14:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 14:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 14:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 15:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 15:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 15:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 16:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 16:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 16:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 17:00:00", 7 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 17:00:00", 7 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 17:00:00", 7 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 18:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 18:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 18:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 19:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 19:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 19:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 20:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 20:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 20:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 21:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 21:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 21:00:00", 4 },
        {"1", "A","2024-02-03 22:00:00", 3 },
        {"2", "B","2024-02-03 22:00:00", 3 },
        {"3", "A","2024-02-03 22:00:00", 3 },
        {"1", "B","2024-02-03 23:00:00", 4 },
        {"2", "A","2024-02-03 23:00:00", 4 },
        {"3", "B","2024-02-03 23:00:00", 4 }
    }
)
```

The peak markers are an adaptation from the Guy In A Cube video ([Guy In A Cube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq-SAaWkycM))(NbPeaks is a parameter).

```
IsHighest = 
VAR _NbHighlight = NbPeaks[NbPeaks Value]
VAR _Ranking = IF (
     ISINSCOPE( 'Table'[DateTimeColumn] ),
     RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED( 'Table'[DateTimeColumn] ),
        [QSumMeasure]
     )
)
VAR _Result = 
    IF ( _Ranking <=_NbHighlight, [QSumMeasure], -100)
RETURN
    _Result
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, I created a measure to calculate the sum of quantities per month :

```
Monthly Quantity = SUMX(SUMMARIZE('TestTable', 'TestTable'[DateTimeColumn], "Month", FORMAT('TestTable'[DateTimeColumn], "YYYYMM"), "MonthlySum", SUM('TestTable'[Quantity])), [MonthlySum])
```

Then I created a measure that checks if the ranking measure equals 1 :

```
IsHighestMonthlyValue = 
VAR CurrentMonth = FORMAT(SELECTEDVALUE('TestTable'[DateTimeColumn]), "YYYYMM")
VAR MonthlyMax = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAXX(SUMMARIZE('TestTable', 'TestTable'[DateTimeColumn], "MonthlySum", [Monthly Quantity]), [MonthlySum]),
        ALL('TestTable'),
        FORMAT('TestTable'[DateTimeColumn], "YYYYMM") = CurrentMonth
    )
RETURN
    IF([Monthly Quantity] = MonthlyMax, 1, 0)
```

[image]

I added the conditional formatting for the data labels like the following :

[image]

[image]

If you want to color the bar also, same logic :

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Update :**

```
IsHighestMonthlyValue = 
VAR CurrentMonth = FORMAT(SELECTEDVALUE('TestTable'[DateTimeColumn]), "YYYYMM")
VAR MonthlyMax = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAXX(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'TestTable', 
                'TestTable'[DateTimeColumn], 
                "MonthlySum", [Monthly Quantity]
            ), 
            [MonthlySum]
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT('TestTable', 'TestTable'[Product], 'TestTable'[ID]),
        FORMAT('TestTable'[DateTimeColumn], "YYYYMM") = CurrentMonth
    )
RETURN
    IF([Monthly Quantity] = MonthlyMax, 1, 0)
```

[image]

Just keep the filters on Product and ID intact and remove others, except for the implicit month-year grouping created by the FORMAT function in the CurrentMonth variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I tested it and it doesn't work if you apply slicers on either ID or Product?

Comment: Thank you. Two follow-up questions. 
1. Calculating the IsHighestMonthlyValue for a large timespan doesn't work due to resource limitations. Can this be used with summarizecolumns or addcolumns instead to better performance?
2. The second measure you created (Rank of Monthly Quantity) isn't used anywhere. Is there a reason you created this?

Comment: 1. what do you mean large timespan and it doesn't work due to resource limitations? the more info you provide in the beggining the better it help us to help you. I can say the solution I provided answers what you provided in the question.
2. dismiss it I used it to test something

Comment: The dataset I'm applying this to is currently a timerange of about 14 months and 27 million rows but this will grow over time. The maximum time range that it allows me to use is about 9 months. The error message is "This visual has exceeded the available resources".  I assume that it is the memory limit of not having a premium capacity. 
I can create a new topic about optimizing this measure and setting your solution as the answer to this topic.